# In angularjs responsive app, why objects loose their value when window is resized?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

So I have been trying to find out that why a object loses all its changes when a window is resized.

```
var buttonStatusObject = {
                    xyzButtonState : {"name":"xyz", "isDisabled": false, "type" : "warning", "size" : 18},
                    xyzButtonState : {"name":"abc", "isDisabled": true, "type" : "warning", "size" : 18},
                    blahButtonState : {"name":"blah", "isDisabled": true, "type" : "warning", "size" : 18},
                    buttonStatus : "active"
            };
```

I create this object when my js file gets loaded. I make some changes in this object on the go and they works fine until I resize the window to a certain level. The problem is that when resized app discard the changes that were made later and show this default value (one shown above). If you resize it back it shows you the changed object.

It feels like my app is maintaining two objects one for the big view and one for the small view. Now I don't know why this thing is happening though I was able to fix this problem by creating a service and adding all the objects into it but can anybody explain me why this thing is happening? I have tried debugging the code in chrome but it is not picking up anything also searched many blogs but no one is explaining this behaviour.

I want to ask why the object loses its changes for small view and retain the values for the normal view? Is it some angular problem of JavaScript problem or something else.

Also I want to add I am using "bootstrap-3.1.1.min.css". The html look like this

```
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-10" style="padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-{{buttonStatusObject.xyzButtonState.type}} ctl-btn-{{buttonStatusObject.xyzButtonState.type}} btn-lg btn-block" ng-style="{'font-size': buttonStatusObject.xyzButtonState.size + 'px'}" ng-disabled="buttonStatusObject.xyzButtonState.isDisabled">{{buttonStatusObject.xyzButtonState.name}}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Probably you are reinitializing the object on resizing

Comment: No I am not reinitializing anything...
Plus as I have stated in the question the object restores its values when resized again...